# std atomic is_lock_free() and is_always_lock_free()

Tags: c++, c++11, lock-free

std::atomic has 1 member function that depends on the object (is_lock_free()) and another that's static constexpr (is_always_lock_free()). Is there any case that some class whose object is sometimes lock_free, sometimes not?